# How to "un-sudo" one command within Python script?

Tags: python, linux, shell, sudo

I have a Python script which I would like to run as `sudo python script.py` since there are many Pygame commands which require sudo permissions.

However, there is just one shell command in the script (using `os.system('...')`) that will not work if run as sudo, but works fine as the standard user outside the script in the command line.

Is there an easy way to "un-sudo" just this one command? Failing this, could I run the script with `python script.py` and have sudo permissions for all lines except the one in question?

Comment: Eh? Why, exactly, does pygame need sudo? If it's for framebuffer access, f'rinstance, the Right Thing is to configure your system to give access to the framebuffer to logged-in users without permissions, not to use sudo.

Comment: If I run the script without sudo, I get the following error:
pygame.display.init()
pygame.error: Unable to open a console terminal

Comment: Right. So configure your framebuffer to be accessible to your user. No need to use sudo there. It might be as easy as adding your user to the 'tty' group and logging out and back in (though the details depend on your operating system).

Comment: but to be fair, that shouldn't really be something a pygame learner needs to know up front is it? most folks wouldn't know not to use sudo there. :(

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to drop permissions with sudo:

```
sudo -u unprivileged-user command ...
```

...but that **doesn't** mean you can get back to the exact state you were in before privileges were escalated; supplemental groups may not be right, security tags may not be right, etc. In short, it's a destructive operation.

Best practice is to avoid needing to escalate permissions at all -- as by giving the user the access it needs for the specific task directly. This specific case sounds like you need framebuffer access; that's easy to provide without root.

If you were in a situation where your script *really* needed escalation for some of its permissions, the best-practices approach is to have your application split into two separate processes -- the one doing the privileged work, and the one doing everything else -- and to use socket or pipeline communication between them. That's a lot of work -- much, much **more** work in most cases than configuring things so that you don't need privilege escalation at all.

Comment: I have added my user "pi" to the group tty (`grep tty /etc/group` confirms this), however running my script with `python script.py` results in alot of initialization errors and permission errors so I have probably missed something.

Comment: Who owns the framebuffer devices is OS-specific -- just because it's the TTY group on some operating systems doesn't mean it's identical everywhere. Have a look at /dev/fb* devices and their permissions -- or, better, use a support forum specific to your operating system. By the way, better to test using the `groups` command than `grep`; `/etc/group` is only read on login, so changes aren't immediate